# Embedded Derby causing out of memory error

Tags: java, out-of-memory, derby, clob, javadb

While Inserting the large data record content say (450kb) using CLOB it is throwing Out of Memory Error. This error is accruing after inserting 200 times data content.

Below is the stack trace of it.

```
DBAppender::updateParameters()::Data.Length()::432164
Exception in thread "AppointmentFileListener" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:101)
```

I tried all the possible solution:

- Ensuring all the resultset statement are close after completing the transaction.
- Setting the CLOB value with `setString(), setClob(), setASCIIStream()`.
- Heap size increment to 1GB and 2GB.

Code snippet

```
public class DBAppender extends AppenderSkeleton
{
    private void initialize() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        if (!EmbeddedDBManager.databaseExists())
        {
            EmbeddedDBManager.createDatabase();
        }
        openConnection();
        thread = new WriteThread();
        // start the thread 
        thread.start();
        initialized = true;
    }
    class WriteThread extends Thread
    {
        final int MAX_UPDATE_ATTEMPTS = 100; // number of times to attempt connection to db
        private volatile boolean stop = false;
        public void stopProcessing()
        {
            stop = true;
        }       
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            LoggingEvent event = null;      
            while (!stop)
            {
                try
                {
                    event = buffer.take();
                    if (event != null)
                    {
                        int tries = 0;
                        while (!stop && tries < MAX_UPDATE_ATTEMPTS)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (connection == null || connection.isClosed())
                                {
                                    openConnection();
                                }       
                                updateParameters(event);
                                statement.execute();
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                tries += 1;                         
                                if (tries < MAX_UPDATE_ATTEMPTS)
                                {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    errorHandler.error("Failed to write event to database", e, ErrorCode.WRITE_FAILURE);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    errorHandler.error("Error in appender WriteThread", e, ErrorCode.FLUSH_FAILURE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void updateParameters(LoggingEvent event) throws SQLException
    {
        statement.clearParameters();
        if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("tracemessages"))
        {
            String data = event.getRenderedMessage();
            statement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(event.getTimeStamp()));
            statement.setLong(2, event.getTimeStamp());
            statement.setString(3, Conversions.field(data, "|", 0));
            statement.setString(4, Conversions.field(data, "|", 1));
            String temp = data.substring(data.indexOf("|", data.indexOf("|") + 1) + 1);
            if (temp.length() > 32600)
            {
                statement.setString(5, temp);
                statement.setString(6, temp.substring(0, 32600));
            }
            else
            {
                statement.setString(5, null);
                statement.setString(6, temp);
            }
            temp = null;
            data = null;
        }
    }
    private String getSQL()
    {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();    
        sql.append("insert into ").append(table);
        if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("traceevents"))
        {
            sql.append("(datetime, msecs, threadid, messageid, correlationid, eventtype, eventobject, entity, execkey, data, reference) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        }
        else
        {
            sql.append("(datetime, msecs, reference, execkey, data, datapart) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        }
        return sql.toString();
    }
    public void close()
    {
        thread.stopProcessing();
        thread.interrupt();
        closeConnection();
        EmbeddedDBManager.removeShutdownListener(this);
        this.closed = true;
    }
    protected void openConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        connection = EmbeddedDBManager.getConnection(EmbeddedDBManager.DEFAULT_DATABASENAME);
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(getSQL());
    }   
}
```

Any suggestion on this really appreciated.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: Code is updated in original post.

Comment: Where in  your code is the exception happening? Can you give a deeper stack trace.

Comment: This statement in updateParameters() statement.setString(5, temp) inserts a clob of size 450KB. When we execute statement.execute() in the WriteThread it throws the exception. Below is the table structure : 

stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE tracemessages (id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (start with 0, increment by 1),  datetime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  msecs BIGINT NOT NULL, reference VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, execkey VARCHAR(100),  data CLOB , datapart LONG VARCHAR, backreference VARCHAR(100), username VARCHAR(100), changed INTEGER)");

Comment: Are you using an in-memory database? See: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdvlpinmemdb.html#cdevdvlpinmemdb

Comment: yes i am using in-memory database.